# Azure API Management - bypass SSL validation

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am playing around with Azure API Management as a SOAP passthrough.  I was hoping to get some analytics in place to preview the service.

My trouble is that my client endpoint has SSL validation in place.  I can't figure out how to load the .cer file in Azure to satisfy this requirement.  At the very least I was hoping to find an option to turn off SSL validation (like I can with curl or even postman).

any one found a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

API Management provides the capability to secure access to the back-end service of an API using client certificates. Below guide shows how to manage certificates in the API publisher portal, and how to configure an API to use a certificate to access its back-end service.

[How to secure back-end services using client certificate authentication in Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates)

Comment: Thanks @Mohit_Garg, if my understanding is correct that is the very for the incoming server.... I need to have ssl validation on the client side. Am I understanding incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the API Management service with https then the certificate that is presented will match the host name that you are calling with.  I'm assuming you were able to change the client to point to your service at https://{servicename}.azure-api.net ?

Or did you change your local hostname file to make that happen?  If that's the case, then that is why you are getting an SSL error.  Without being able to re-compile your client you cannot disable the SSL validation.

You could configure the custom domain in API Management and if you have access to the certificate, you could attach it to the custom domain.  However, you would actually have to change the public DNS for the domain to make that work.  I don't think you can enable a custom domain in API Management, provide the certificate and only use your local hostname file to do the mapping.  But I will check.

Answer (score 0):

The steps under 'Scenario 7: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel' in [Troubleshooting 4xx and 5xx Errors with Azure APIM services](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/troubleshooting-4xx-and-5xx-errors-with-azure-apim-services/ba-p/2115744) is what worked for me. I'm using this approach to bypass validating the SSL cert until I switch from using a self-signed cert to a CA signed one.